# Recursive menu of all children

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to generate a nested menu of all the pages in the site tree.

The [docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/navigation_menu) show two levels - I won't know how many levels there are.

Currently I know there is at least four levels deep at one point so I have this:

```php
<ul>
<% loop $Menu(1) %>
    <li>
        <a href="$Link" title="Go to the $Title page" class="<% if $isCurrent %>current<% else_if $isSection %>section<% end_if %>">
            $MenuTitle
        </a>

        <% if $Children %>
        <ul>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <li class="<% if $isCurrent %>current<% else_if $isSection %>section<% end_if %>">
                <a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a>

                <% if $Children %>
                <ul>
                <% loop $Children %>
                    <li class="<% if $isCurrent %>current<% else_if $isSection %>section<% end_if %>">
                        <a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a>

                        <% if $Children %>
                        <ul>
                        <% loop $Children %>
                            <li class="<% if $isCurrent %>current<% else_if $isSection %>section<% end_if %>">
                                <a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a>
                            </li>
                        <% end_loop %>
                        </ul>
                        <% end_if %>

                    </li>
                <% end_loop %>
                </ul>
                <% end_if %>

            </li>
        <% end_loop %>
        </ul>
        <% end_if %>

    </li>
<% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

It works but is unreliable (if an editor adds another level). It is pretty janky. Is there a recursive option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a recursive menu item template to create a menu that goes as deep as the site tree.

First we create a `MenuItem.ss` template file in our theme's `Includes` directory. In this template we display the menu item link and check if there are any children pages. We loop through any children pages and include the `MenuItem.ss` template for each:

**Includes/MenuItem.ss**

```
<li class="$LinkingMode">
    <a href="$Link" aria-label="Go to the $Title.XML page">$MenuTitle</a>

    <% if $Children %>
    <ul>
        <% loop $Children %>
        <% include Includes/MenuItem %>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
    <% end_if %>
</li>
```

Our main menu code in our template then becomes the following:

```
<nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <% loop $Menu(1) %>
        <% include Includes/MenuItem %>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
</nav>
```